# Multi-user sharing excel files and automated refresh

Tags: excel

Any recommendation on having a shared excel file auto-refresh itself?

We will need 3 users of an excel file on the fileserver. One user will be making changes. Others are read-only, but they must see the change as quickly as possible. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

In your excel file you need to enable workbook sharing (in 2007 it's the Review Ribbon, Share Workbook).  On the advanced tab you can set the "Update changes" to an interval as low as 5 minutes and set it to "Just see other users' changes".

Jesse

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone is still interested in this but there are far more sophisticated tools to do this now.

Checkout https://www.ipushpull.com

Disclaimer (just so I don't get too much hate): I am affiliated with ipushpull

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what server tools you're working with.

If it's just a shared excel file on a server, if one user has it open others will only be allowed to open a read only version, regardless of what their permissions are.  When the first user saves their changes, other users can view the updates by reopening the file (again, in read only mode if the first user still has the file open, and/or if their permissions are set to read only).

If you're on a system like sharepoint you can do the kinds of things you're looking for.

This may help:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-sharing-and-collaborating-on-excel-data-HA010089896.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Save main excel file (A) on the server and give access to editor so that he can edit. Copy same file and name it (B) and link it to main file (A) to read data and protect. You can do this simply by referencing respective cells to main file. Distribute copies of file (B) to users to read the data.

How to link?: Open both files on your PC, in file (B) Sheet-1 click in Cell A1, type = and go to File (A) Sheet-1 and click in Cell A1. In formula bar if cell reference is absolute ('[(A).xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1) change it to normal ('[(A).xlsx]Sheet1'!A1) by hitting F4 3 times. and hit Enter. Cell A1 in File (B) has been linked to respective cell in main file (A).
Now select cell A1 in file (B) and drag it towards last required cell on right then select line 1 and drag downwards as required. Now the whole page is linked back to your file (A). Similarly do for other sheets. Any changes done on file (A) will reflect in File (B) in real time if both are open, otherwise on reopening file (B) you will be asked to update, click yes and that is it. Hope this helps.