# Checking file open vb.net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio, excel-2013

I created a form in visual studio 2013 which populates data into excel file. When the form is loaded, the file becomes visible for the users.

My excel file will be shared by multiple users. The problem is my code rewrites the other person's data. 
How do I refresh the excel file so that on all computers all users can see the newly made changes?

Please help.

EDIT: My code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    workbook.ReadOnlyRecommended = True
    Dim row As Long
    Dim alpha As Long = 0
    row = 5
    With worksheet
        Do While .Cells(row, 4).value IsNot Nothing
            row = row + 1
        Loop

        .Cells(row, 2).value = Me.fname.Text
        .Cells(row, 3).value = Me.lname.Text
        Me.fullname.Text = Me.fname.Text + Me.lname.Text
        .Cells(row, 4).value = Me.fullname.Text

    End With
    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
    workbook.ReadOnlyRecommended = False

    If workbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        workbook.AcceptAllChanges()
        workbook.Save()
    End If

    workbook.SaveAs("\test.xlsx",AccessMode:=excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared)
    workbook.Close()
    Call Form1_Load(sender, EventArgs.Empty)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain why I am getting negative votes on this question!

Comment: Will be the fact you've basically asked SO users to write you code rather than showing what you've tried and your research. Also doesn't help with the **It's urgent** like we should all drop what we are doing :)

Comment: I am sorry didn't mean that. I added my code @Jinx88909

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-user sharing excel files and automated refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536051/multi-user-sharing-excel-files-and-automated-refresh) You'd likely have fewer headaches if you moved your data to a database, which was really meant to share data rather than the hack they applied to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved using:

```
If workbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        workbook.AcceptAllChanges()
        workbook.Save()
    End If
```